# php command not found

Tags: php, linux, command, execute, pdf2swf

I am using Php in Linux Cent OS. I wanted to convert PDF to SWF, So I use SWFTools. SWFTools consists of pdf2swf command, which is executing fine when I use it in command line. But the command is not working when I execute it through php.

Error: command not found

I have found the extensions are up to date.

Anything else is missing in between?

Comment: How do you "execute it through php"?

Comment: please add your code you are using in phpscript?

Comment: what are you using to execute the command?

Comment: please add command that you are trying. its difficult to understand from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the full path.

The path environmental variable will be different when running under PHP, since that will run as another user.

Comment: This is how I am using:                                                    $command = "pdf2swf ".getcwd()."/".$pdfFile." -o ".getcwd()."/".$swfFile." -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters";
                                                                                            
exec($command,$output,$return_var);